# Need help with Bulk API

Tags: bulk-api, asynchronous

I know that Bulk API is an asynchronous API. I understood Bulk API, going through the developer guide, but have a question unanswered. When a job completes or a batch completes, is there a notification from the Salesforce side, notifying the same. Because after creating the job, and submitting all the batches to it, how to know that your job is done?

For now, I am thinking of polling on regular intervals to check on the status of the job, and get to know that all of my batches are done. But wanted to get if there is an efficient alternative available?

Another reason to avoid, the above mentioned polling option, since it adds to the 24hrs API limits for my developer org.

Also, if anyone has any used this polling approach, what would be a sufficient polling interval?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately , Salesforce does not notifies when the Bulk data jobs gets completed. Salesforce only provides information under `setup->Bulk data load jobs`. So polling is the only option here.

I had this situation, where an external system pushes data into Salesforce using bulk API during early morning hours. I created a custom object to record the details- jobid, #of records processed, Status etc.. of the Job when it starts.

At night I have a job scheduled which uses the JobId stored on the custom object and use it to check the result( by then surely the bulk api jobs would have completed). So bulk api job runs in the morning and polling job runs once at night.

The polling job hit the bulk api job status endpoint to check the status of bulk api and other informations like #of records processed etc. The polling job updates the custom object records with the information obtained. Hence there is a record about what happened. Polling interval depends on the amount data and the time when you are loading the data. I have seen 4 million records getting inserted in less than 15 min using bulk api(batch size 10000). So if you have one time load daily at a specific time, you can schedule the polling job may be after an hour or schedule it later in the day to be safe. But if you have jobs getting created very frequently through out the day then best approach is to poll at night and record/email the results.